# Django media root image doesn't load in template

Tags: django, image, templates, media, root

I've searched other django media image issues threads and none of those helped me really, most problems were about linking the image correctly in template  tag. I have another problem, its linked correctly, which I can see when I inspect the element inside the browser, but still it doesn't load up.

Here are the actual codes from

models.py :

```
class user(models.Model):
    ime = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    prezime = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    slika = models.ImageField(upload_to='slike/profili/')
```

views.py :

```
def board(requset):
    profili = user.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('board.html', {'profili': profili})
```

board.html :

```
<div>
{% for profil in profili %}
    <div><p style=" color:white;position: relative; left: 50%"><img src="{{ profil.slika.url }}" width="256px" height="256px">THIS IS AN IMAGE</p></div>
    <div><p style="color: white; position: relative; left: 50%;">{{ profil.ime }}</p></div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

settings.py :

```
MEDIA_ROOT = 'C:/Users/Prototype/Documents/PythonProjs/SKOLA/media/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

What seems to be the problem?

Comment: What does your code outputs on the html after rendering the template?

Comment: <img src="/media/slike/profili/avatar_4efGJwh.png" width="256px" height="256px"> just like it should

Comment: What happens if you try to access to your_site:your_port/media/slike/profili/avatar_4efGJwh.png? If you can't access the link and it displays a 404 (Not Found) error, the trouble is in your settings.py MEDIA configuration.

Comment: Also, remember to register in your urls.py the MEDIA_ROOT like [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development)

Comment: Ok, I'ts fixed now. Thank you @avenet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you serve static files on your urls.py. To do this, check the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development).

Note this approach will only work for development (using `DEBUG=True`), for production consider serving files via Apache or Nginx.